# Casting as a sksprite node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I keep getting a SIGBRT error on this line of code:

```
let spriteTapped : SKSpriteNode = (nodeTapped as? SKSpriteNode)!
```

I am using it to check if my sprite is tapped and which one is tapped, I get this error whenever anything other than a SKSpriteNode is tapped, any ideas on how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `nodeTapped` is *not* a `SKSpriteNode` then the conditional cast
`nodeTapped as? SKSpriteNode`
evaluates to `nil`, and the forced unwrapping with `!` crashes.
Better use optional binding:

```
if let spriteTapped = nodeTapped as? SKSpriteNode {
    // ... do something with spriteTapped ...
} else {
    // tapped node is not a SKSpriteNode
}
```

or

```
guard let spriteTapped = nodeTapped as? SKSpriteNode else {
    return // tapped node is not a SKSpriteNode
}
// ... do something with spriteTapped ...
```

If you have an *array* of nodes then

```
for case let spriteTapped as SKSpriteNode in nodesTapped {
    // ... do something with spriteTapped ...
}
```

can be used to iterate over all sprite nodes in the list (and
silently ignore other nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Answer by *@Martin R* is totally correct.

Let me add more details about detecting which nodes or sprites have been tapped.

If you add this to your scene

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    let tappedNodes = nodes(at: location)
    let tappedSprites = tappedNodes.compactMap { $0 as? SKSpriteNode }

}
```

you can easily get the list of all the nodes (`tappedNodes`) and the sprites (`tappedSprites`) having the same coordinates of your touch.